# ReplyError: ERR invalid expire time in set - redis - Node.js

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I have a Node.js web application which uses redis as session storage. Some requests receive the following ReplyError while trying to `save` the session:

```
ReplyError: ERR invalid expire time in set
   at parseError (.../node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:179:12)
   at parseType (.../node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:302:14)
```

I checked the specified file but I couldn't find anything which might cause it. Also, as far as I know, `set` method doesn't receive a expire time argument. I would very much appreciate any pointers as to how to fix it or what may cause it.

OS: `Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS`
NodeJS version: `12.19.0`
redis-server version: `4.0.9`
node-redis version: `3.0.2`
node-redis-parser version: `3.0.0`

Comment: `SET` doesn't accept as argument but accept as an `option` named `EX`. https://redis.io/commands/set#options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a known issue with manually saving a session in `connect-redis`. More info can be found at https://github.com/tj/connect-redis/issues/292.